# Copying data from a Winforms ListView

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

Is there a way to copy the text of the selected subitem from a ListView in .NET Winforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm really missing something fundamental, you can't select a subitem.  You can select the subitem in the first column or you can set the FullRowSelect property to True.  Neither helps you to determine what subitem the user might be interested in, there's no way to guess what to copy to the clipboard.

Use DataGridView to work around that.

Comment: you can determine what subitem the mouse was over when the mouse was clicked by using the ListView.HitTest() function

Comment: yeah it seems like a hack, and a datagridview is nice choice if that will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Each item inside of a `ListView` control is represented by a `ListViewItem`. The `ListViewItem` has a property called `SubItems` which starts from the very first column of data in the `ListView` control.

To copy data from a column, get the selected `ListViewItem` and reference the `Text` property available from the `SubItems` property.

For example,

```
int theSelectedIndex = 0; // this should be the index of your selected item in the list
int theSubItemIndex = 0; // this should be the index of the subitem whose text you want to copy

ListViewItem lvItem = listView1.SelectedItems[theSelectedIndex];
string text = lvItem.SubItems[theSubItemIndex].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will give you the sub item value and sub item column name (if you store the col name in the tag value of the sub item when you create it.

```
Point workItemsListViewLastHit;

private void workItemsListView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    workItemsListViewLastHit = e.Location;
}


private void workItemsListView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewHitTestInfo HTI = workItemsListView.HitTest(workItemsListViewLastHit);

     if (HTI.Item != null)
     {
               string field = HTI.SubItem.Tag as string;
               string value = HTI.SubItem.Text;
     }
}
```